# Add a list to a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to add a list within each tableview cell that will go to the right of an image. Each list may create new items and remove them. Each item is it's own textView that will show all of the lines. I want the cell to be able to resize itself based on the height of the list.

I've tried using sections but I want the header to be to the left of the list, not above.

I've looked at trying to make each UITableViewCell it's own tableView and put the list in there. However, I think it will be difficult to determine the size of it since some list items will be more than one line.

I've thought about adding stack views to help with the dynamic resizing of the cell.

Is there a good way to do this? Is there a different approach?

Comment: Are you sure UITableView is the right approach? This smells of UICollectionView which might work better.